# Updating many objects at once using Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I need to update particular fields of multiple objects stored in a class. I can do this from the client, but I don't like the idea of it handling that extra bandwidth. How can I update and save objects I've iterated over in a Cloud Code query? Essentially, what's the JS equivalent of the following Swift method?

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      for object in objects {
        // Update object here
      }

      // Save your changes to ALL objects
      PFObject.saveAllInBackground()
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateScores", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("GameScore");
    query.equalTo("playerName", "Sean Plott");
    query.each(function (object) {
        // Do something with object
        object.save();
    }).then(function (success) {
        request.success("OK");
    }, function(err) {
        request.error(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to update multiple objects with the same value. Would I call object.set() to do the actual update? Let's say a blogger changes his username, I want to update each of his blogs with the updated username of the blogger.

Comment: Yes, you can try object.set("Score", newScore)

Comment: I'm getting `[Error]: success/error was not called (Code: 141, Version: 1.7.2)`